# media queries min width doesn't work

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I have two media queries.

```
@media (min-width: 1300px) {
    .container {
        width: auto;
        max-width: 1360px;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 1565px) {
    .container {
        width: auto;
        max-width: 1576px;
    }
}
```

whatever the width is. the container always as the first media query. 
 I mean when the width of body is 1570px the container width still 1360px !

Comment: use max-width:1576px !important;

Answer (score 10):

It's important to set the [viewport](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag) in the HTML `<head>`.

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`

Answer (score 1):

Just reverse the @media query order.

```
@media (min-width: 1565px) {
    .container {
        width: auto;
        max-width: 1576px;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 1300px) {
    .container {
        width: auto;
        max-width: 1360px;
    }
}
```

Comment: same problem. the container always 1576px -as it is first media query - even if the body with is 1500px for example.

Comment: can u share your link?

Comment: it is local page. what do you mean by my link ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
@media only screen and (min-width:1300px) and (max-width: 1565px)  {
    .container {
        width: auto;
        max-width: 1360px;
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-width:1565px) {
    .container {
        width: auto;
        max-width: 1576px;
    }
}
```

Comment: doesn't work. when I put body width 1550px. the container is 1576px !

Comment: @kroaine your (max-width: 1565px) needs to be a pixel smaller than your (min-width:1565px) So  (max-width: 1564px) (min-width:1565px)

Comment: even so, with same value in `max-width` and `min-width` it works fine, I think the problem is another

Comment: CSS overriding will be there, shouldn't be a problem, maybe `width:100%; display:block;` should be in compliment to `.container` style

Comment: Media queries aren't affect to body, but to document width.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there are other ways to achieve what you are looking for. I would not advise you to stack up min-width queries like that, but rather design your website to behave in a certain way regardless of the minimum width, and only use the media queries for smaller screens, using max-width.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
@media only screen and (min-width:1300px) and (max-width: 1564px)  {
    .container {
        max-width: 1360px;
        width: 100%;
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-width:1565px) {
    .container {
        max-width: 1576px;
        width: 100%;

    }
}
```